# Where can i find RDDTool php extension for Windows?

Tags: php, windows, rrdtool

i'm trying to use RDDTool with my apache/php5 on Windows but i can't find the extension for php.. 
can you help me ?  does it exist ? how can i do with the rrdtool.exe only ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you tried using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)?

Comment: Related: http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/25/how-to-build-the-php-rrdtool-extension-by-hand/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried install RRDTool extension from PECL (http://pecl.php.net/package/rrd/download/1.0.0/) ?

You need to build it for you. http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Second solution ; you can call rddtool via shell_exec() function.